# AnimatedSize clipping the widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm creating a bottom navigation bar. When the app launches, the default selected navigation tab extends as seen in the gif.

The issue is when `AnimatedSize` starts the animate, borders cuts off. Therefore, the container's border-radius doesn't look good. I don't think I'm clipping the view. What am I missing?

[image]

[**slide_box.dart**](https://gist.github.com/buraktabn/9bd41c3ecc65ac8eb797b3c274155a26)

```dart
AnimatedSize(
  curve: Curves.ease,
  child: new Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: _topPadding),
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Container(
      width: _width,
      height: _height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: _service.settings.color,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 5),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
          boxShadow: [BoxShadow(offset: Offset(0, 3), blurRadius: 6, color: const Color(0xff000000).withOpacity(0.16))]),
    ),
  ),
  vsync: this,
  duration: _service.animationDuration,
),
```

**main.dart**

```dart
return Container(
  height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      if (service.isBottomSlideVisible) SlideBox(),
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: service.items
                .map((e) => NavItem(
                      e,
                      onTab: () {
                        var index = service.items.indexOf(e);
                        service.setSelected(index);
                        _updateIndex(index);
                      },
                    ))
                .toList()),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: this might help https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/animated-container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Wrap the `AnimatedSize` with a `Container` and add borders to the `Container`.

**2.** Set height of the `Container` to `_height`.

**3.** Add a top margin of `_topPadding` to the `Container`.

**4.** Subtract the border width of the `Container` from the `left` parameter of the `AnimatedPositioned` to center the content.

**5.** Remove the borders from the inner `Container`.

```
AnimatedPositioned(
            left: _posX - _sizeFactor - 5,
            child: Container(
              height: _height,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: _topPadding),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: _service.settings.color,
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 5),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                  boxShadow: _service.settings.shadow ??
                      [
                        BoxShadow(
                            offset: Offset(0, 3),
                            blurRadius: 6,
                            color: const Color(0xff000000).withOpacity(0.16))
                      ]),
              child: AnimatedSize(
                curve: Curves.ease,
                child: new Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: _topPadding),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Container(
                    width: _width,
                    height: _height,
                  ),
                ),
                vsync: this,
                duration: _service.animationDuration,
              ),
            ),
            duration: _service.animationDuration,
            curve: Curves.easeOutCirc,
          ),
```

**Result:**

[image]